# php recursive array merging

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have 2 arrays:

```
$bigArr = array(
    'simple'=>1
    'advanced'=>array(
        'advanceSimple'=>1,
        'advanceadvance'=>array(
            'simple'=>1
        )  
    )
)

$overide = array(
    'advanced'=>array(
        'advanceSimple'=>2,
        'extra'=>5
    )
)
```

the merge of those 2 should be:

```
$bigArr = array(
    'simple'=>1
    'advanced'=>array(
        'advanceSimple'=>2,
        'extra'=>5,
        'advanceadvance'=>array(
            'simple'=>1
        )  
    )
)
```

you see that the overiden of the small array will overide only where the keys exist, and will add data where it doesnt exist.

I tried many ways of recursive iterator and loops, but still no go.

Do you have any ideas or similar workarounds.

Comment: Have you tried using `array_merge`?

Comment: may be what you need is array_merge_recursive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$bigArr = array(
    'simple'=>1,
    'advanced'=>array(
        'advanceSimple'=>1,
        'advanceadvance'=>array(
            'simple'=>1
        )  
    )
);
$overide = array(
    'advanced'=>array(
        'advanceSimple'=>2,
        'extra'=>5
    )
);
$res = array_merge_recursive($bigArr,$overide);
```

is that what you need?

Comment: its not as the required result.. advanceSimple becomes array with entries.. instead of integer

Answer (score 0):

Answer for PHP 5.3 +

```
$bigArr = array(
    'simple'=>1,
    'advanced'=>array(
        'advanceSimple'=>1,
        'advanceadvance'=>array(
            'simple'=>1
        )
    )
);
$overide = array(
    'advanced'=>array(
        'advanceSimple'=>2,
        'extra'=>5
    )
);
$array = array_replace_recursive($bigArr,$overide);
echo "<pre>";
print_R($array);
```